Significant Delay in M3U Playlist Parsing with Completion Handler using M3UKit
I've built a simple app to test some packages for downloading and parsing M3U playlists.
I'm using M3Ukit package: link
When I press the "Test1" button, which runs on the main thread, I immediately receive the playlist response. The download takes just a few seconds. However, when I use the "Test2" button with a completion handler, it takes over 30 seconds to get a response, even though the playlist is the same.
I'm trying to understand why there's such a significant difference in response times. Am I missing something, or is there something I don't understand about how the completion handler is affecting the process?
Here my code:
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import M3UKit

@main
struct diptvApp: App {
    @State private var manager = Manager()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(manager)
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(Manager.self) private var manager
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                manager.parsetest1()
            } label: {
                Text("Test 1")
            }
            Button {
                manager.parsetest2()
            } label: {
                Text("Test 2")
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


@Observable class Manager {
    
    let parser = PlaylistParser()
    let linkTV: String = "https://iptv-org.github.io/iptv/index.m3u"

    
    
    
    func parsetest1(){
        do {
            let url = URL(string: linkTV)!
            let result = try parser.parse(url)
            print("found \(result.medias.count)")
        }catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    func parsetest2(){
        
        let url = URL(string: linkTV)!
        parser.parse(url, processingQueue: .global(qos: .background)) { result in
            
            switch result {
                
            case .success(let playlist):
                print("found \(playlist.medias.count)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("found error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    
}



Change your queue to a higher priority
